# How to divide sentence into two by two parts?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split

I have following type of sentences. I want to divide sentence into two by two parts like following example.

Example:

```
Nimal read/write book/newspaper from his pen.
```

I want to divide following way above sentence and add into arraylist.

```
Nimal/read
Nimal/write
read/book
read/newspaper
write/book
write/newspaper
book/from
newspaper/from
from/his
his/pen.
```

That's mean I want to get two words phrases from the next word.I have divide and added sentences.But I haven't clear idea to what next to do.

```
    ArrayList<String> wordArrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String sentence="Nimal read/write book/newspaper from his pen";
    for(String wordTw0 : sentence.split(" ")) {
        wordArrayList2.add(wordTw0);
    }
```

Comment: regex will not help in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple program using `String#split()` method.

steps to follow:

1. split the whole string based on one or more spaces.
2. iterate all the strings from the array till length-1.
3. get two strings from the array at a time from (i)th and (i+1)th position
4. split both the strings based on forward slash
5. iterate both the array and make words joining then by forward slash
6. add all the words in the list.

Sample code:

```
String str = "Nimal read/write book/newspaper from his pen.";

ArrayList<String> wordArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] array = str.split("\\s+"); // split based on one or more space
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    String s1 = array[i];
    String s2 = array[i + 1];

    String[] a1 = s1.split("/"); //split based on forward slash
    String[] b1 = s2.split("/"); //split based on forward slash
    for (String a : a1) {
        for (String b : b1) {
            String word = a + "/" + b;
            wordArrayList.add(word);
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Nimal/read
Nimal/write
read/book
read/newspaper
write/book
write/newspaper
book/from
newspaper/from
from/his
his/pen.
```